# Merging multiple pdf files into single pdf using unix command

Tags: unix

I want to merge multiple pdf file into single pdf file using unix command.Could someone provide me a solution.

Comment: They probably could only be compressed/archived into a tarball,not a pdf!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman Why exactly couldn't you create a new PDF with the contents of multiple other PDFs?

Comment: @Juhana-Sorry,but,I've never heard/done that using unix terminal! Then,please post a solution so that people like me could know!

Answer (score 2):

The [Poppler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_%28software%29) folks have produced a `pdfunite` utility which should do what you want.

In Ubuntu (and possibly other Unixy systems) it is in the poppler-utils package.

You run it with `pdfunite file1.pdf file2.pdf ... combinedfile.pdf`.

So if, for instance, you had a whole lot of files named file01.pdf, file02.pdf, file03.pdf, ... and wanted to merge them all, `pdfunite file?? combined.pdf` from the command line should do the job.